# GCC Casting Pointer to Incompatible Type

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, struct

I have a working C code when compiled using GCC, but I am trying to find out if the code works because of pure luck or because GCC handles this code as I expect by design.

**NOTE**
**I am not trying to "fix" it. I am trying to understand the compiler**

Here is what I have:

**iexample.h**

```
#ifndef IEXAMPLE_H_
#define IEXAMPLE_H_


/* The interface */
struct MyIf
{
  int (* init)(struct MyIf* obj);
  int (* push)(struct MyIf* obj, int x);
  void (* sort)(struct MyIf* obj);

};


/* The object, can be in different header */
struct Obj1
{
  struct MyIf myinterface;
  int val1;
  int val2;

};

struct Obj1* newObj1();

#endif
```

**iexample.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>

#include "iexample.h"

/* Functions here are "equivalent" to methods on the Obj1 struct */

int Obj1_init(struct Obj1* obj)
{
  printf("Obj1_init()\n");
  return 0;
}

int Obj1_push(struct Obj1* obj, int x)
{
  printf("Obj1_push()\n");
  return 0;
}

void Obj1_sort(struct Obj1* obj)
{
  printf("Obj1_sort()\n");
}

struct Obj1* newObj1()
{
  struct Obj1* obj = malloc(sizeof(struct Obj1));
  obj->myinterface.init = Obj1_init;
  obj->myinterface.push = Obj1_push;
  obj->myinterface.sort = Obj1_sort;
  return obj;

}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "iexample.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  struct MyIf* myIf = (struct MyIf*) newObj1();
  myIf->init(myIf);
  myIf->push(myIf, 3);
  myIf->sort(myIf);
  /* ... free, return ... */
}
```

When I compile, **as I expect**, I get for assigning the pointers in newObj1(),

```
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

The code works as long as I have the "struct MyIf myinterface" to be the first member of the struct, which is by design (I like to shoot myself in the foot)

Now, although I am assigning incompatible pointer types, and the C spec says behavior is undefined, does GCC or other compilers make any design claim on how this case is handled? I can almost swear that this OUGHT TO WORK due to how struct memory is laid out, but I cannot find the proof.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C11 standard 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers:

> Within  a  structure  object,  the  non-bit-field  members  and  the 
>   units  in  which  bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in
>   the order in which they are declared.  A pointer to a structure 
>   object,  suitably  converted,  points  to  its  initial  member  (or 
>   if  that  member  is  a bit-field,  then  to  the  unit  in  which  it
>   resides),  and  vice  versa.   There  may  be  unnamed padding within
>   a structure object, but not at its beginning.

So it should work as long, as you access only first structure member. However, I believe you understand, that this is pretty bad idea. Should you port this code to C++ and make some `Obj1` member virtual, this will immediately fail.

Comment: +1 for giving not so trivial example on how it can fail and also showing the spec. I was looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @M.M Is it though? Doesn't the given citation show that it has to work this way according to the standard?

Comment: @sepp2k No, the quotation only talks about struct layout

Comment: @M.M It says the address of the struct will always equal the address of the first member, right? So doesn't it follow from that, that a valid pointer to a struct will also be a valid pointer to the first memberwhen cast to the member's type?

Comment: sepp2k, I reached the conclusion that sepp2k is wrong. This code is correct. Searching for "Objected Oriented C pdf" shows results with similar techniques.